# Retrieving the primary Key column

Tags: 7, database

I have been using this query to [query Postgres Table Primary Key Column](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Retrieve_primary_key_columns).

```
SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) AS data_type
FROM   pg_index i
JOIN   pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = i.indrelid
                     AND a.attnum = ANY(i.indkey)
WHERE  i.indrelid = 'semstudent'::regclass
AND    i.indisprimary;
```

I want to perform the above query in Drupal. Below is my code:

```
$query=db_select('pg_index', 'i',array('target' => 'import'));  
$query->join('pg_attribute' , 'a' ,'a.attrelid = i.indrelid AND a.attnum = ANY(i.indkey)');                 
$result = $query
    ->fields('a', array('attname','atttypid','atttypmod'))  
    ->condition('i.indrelid', '"semstudent"::regclass')     
    ->condition('i.indisprimary', true) 
    ->execute();
```

The query above create the error below:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type oid: ""semstudent"::regclass"
>       LINE 5: WHERE  (i.indrelid = '"semstudent"::regclass') AND   (i.indisp...
>                                ^: SELECT a.attname AS attname, a.atttypid AS atttypid,   a.atttypmod AS atttypmod
>       FROM 
>       {pg_index} i
>       INNER JOIN {pg_attribute} a ON a.attrelid = i.indrelid AND a.attnum =     ANY(i.indkey)
>       WHERE  (i.indrelid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (i.indisprimary =   :db_condition_placeholder_1) ; Array
>       (
>           [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => "semstudent"::regclass
>           [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 1
>       )
>       in myid_get_template_table_primary_key() (line 755 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal-  7.34\sites\all\modules\myid\includes\myid_inputting.inc).

I guess it has something to do with the statement below.

```
->condition('i.indrelid', '"semstudent"::regclass')
```

How do I convert it?

UPDATE:

Suggestions below are appreciated but it doesnt make any changes in my code. I have somehow managed to get it working manually. See code below:

```
 $database = 'import';
 $table = 'semstudent';

 $query=db_select('pg_index', 't1',array('target' => $database));
 $query->join('pg_attribute' , 't2' ,'t2.attrelid = t1.indrelid AND t2.attnum = ANY(t1.indkey)');                   
 $result = $query
    ->fields('t2', array('attname','atttypid','atttypmod'))  
    ->condition('t1.indrelid', myid_get_table_oid($table, $database)) 
    ->condition('t1.indisprimary', true) 
    ->execute();
```

I have made the function `myid_get_table_oid` supplied with two parameters: `$table` and `$database`. $table represents the name of the the table. $database represents the target database.

```
//A function that returns the oid of a particular table.
function myid_get_table_oid($table_name, $database){

    $query=db_select('pg_class ', 't1',array('target' => $database));                       
    $result = $query
        ->fields('t1', array('relfilenode'))  
        ->condition('t1.relname', $table_name)          
        ->execute();

    $oid = '';
    foreach($result as $record){     
        $oid = $record->relfilenode;
        break;
    }       
    return $oid;
}
```

In many instances, the code I made is working but there is one scenario the function returns no primary key. When I use the code above with a particular table `myid_template_27` in my database. The function `myid_get_table_oid` returns an oid    `8948915`. But the converted query doesnt return anything.

I am pretty sure that the table `myid_template_27` have a primary key column. It must return the column `biginta`.See image below:

[image]

To see if `biginta` really exist on `pg_attribute` table, I made a query below:

```
SELECT t1.indrelid, t2.attname AS attname, t2.atttypid AS atttypid, t2.atttypmod       
AS atttypmod
FROM pg_index t1
INNER JOIN pg_attribute t2 ON t2.attrelid = t1.indrelid AND t2.attnum =     ANY(t1.indkey)
WHERE  (t1.indisprimary = true)  AND (t2.attname = 'biginta')
```

The result shows a different `indrelid` `oid` which is different from the value returned by my function `myid_get_table_oid`.

[image]

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Do you get any error, or is the result not the expected one? In the former case, please report the error you are getting; in the latter case, please report what you are getting and in which way is different from what you are expecting.

Comment: "Invalid text representation" is probably talking about the quotes, try reversing them (`->condition('i.indrelid', "'semstudent'::regclass")  `

Comment: try `>condition('i.indrelid', semstudent::regclass)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As some people already mentioned and the error itself describes, this is a variable interpolation/auto-quoting problem.

The most appropriate option here - following the D.O.'s documentation - would be to use `where()`, instead of `condition()`.

> $query->where($snippet, $args = array())
>
> The where() method allows for the addition of arbitrary SQL as a conditional fragment. $snippet may contain any legal SQL fragment, and
>   if it has variable content it must be added using a named placeholder.
>   The $args array is an array of placeholders and values that will be
>   substituted into the snippet. It is up to the developer to ensure that
>   the snippet is valid SQL. No database-specific modifications are made
>   to the snippet.
>
> (*Copied from https://www.drupal.org/node/310086*)

And here is a rewrite of your code:

```
$query=db_select('pg_index', 'i',array('target' => 'import'));  
$query->join('pg_attribute' , 'a' ,'a.attrelid = i.indrelid AND a.attnum = ANY(i.indkey)');                 
$result = $query
    ->fields('a', array('attname','atttypid','atttypmod'))  
    ->where("i.indrelid = 'semstudent'::regclass")
    ->condition('i.indisprimary', true) 
    ->execute();
```

I just tried this and it worked without any problems, hope it works for you too!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [db_query](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7) It will be clear to write the same query with minimal edit.

```
 db_query('SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) AS data_type
    FROM   pg_index i
    JOIN   pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = i.indrelid
                         AND a.attnum = ANY(i.indkey)
    WHERE  i.indrelid = :tablename::regclass
    AND    i.indisprimary', array(':tablename' => $tablename));
```